# FltRegisterFilter referenced in Function DriverEntry in filter.obj

Tags: c++, minifilter

Basically I am trying create a simple FileSystem MiniFilter Driver where I can modify a notepad file from writing. Following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rErMsfmK_U&list=PLZ4EgN7ZCzJyUT-FmgHsW4e9BxfP-VMuo&index=12). So I created a project in visual studio which is type `Filter Driver: NDIS`. here is the full code:

```
/*++

Module Name:

    Filter.c

Abstract:

    Sample NDIS Lightweight filter driver

--*/

#include "precomp.h"

PFLT_FILTER FilterHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags);
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);


const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    {IRP_MJ_CREATE,0,MiniPreCreate,MiniPostCreate},
    {IRP_MJ_WRITE,0,MiniPreCreate,NULL},
    {IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END}
};
const FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,
    0,
    NULL,
    Callbacks,
    MiniUnload,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags) {
    KdPrint(("driver unload \r\n"));
    FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags) {
    KdPrint(("Post Create is running \r\n"));
    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                _wcsupr(Name);
                if (wcsstr(Name, L"OPENME.TXT") != NULL) {
                    KdPrint(("Write File: %ws Blocked \r\n", Name));
                    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
                    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                }
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}


NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &FilterHandle);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltStartFiltering(FilterHandle);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

The header files have been to `precomp.h` as below:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4201)  //nonstandard extension used : nameless struct/union
#pragma warning(disable:4100)
#include <fltKernel.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>
#include <ndis.h>
#include <filteruser.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include "flt_dbg.h"
#include "filter.h"
```

Everything else is default.

Project configuration is Active(x64) under properties.

With all of that I am getting below errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltGetFileNameInformation referenced in function MiniPreCreate   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Warning 1324    [Version] section should specify PnpLockdown=1 to prevent external apps from modifying installed driver files.  default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\default.inf 8   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltRegisterFilter referenced in function DriverEntry default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltUnregisterFilter referenced in function MiniUnload    default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltStartFiltering referenced in function DriverEntry default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltReleaseFileNameInformation referenced in function MiniPreCreate   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FltParseFileNameInformation referenced in function MiniPreCreate default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\filter.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol FilterDriverHandle   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol FilterDriverObject   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol NdisFilterDeviceHandle   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol NdisDeviceObject default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol FilterListLock   default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol FilterModuleList default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\default\device.obj  1   
Error   LNK1120 12 unresolved externals default C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\default\x64\Debug\default.sys   1
```

Can Anyone guide on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [*Library FltMgr.lib*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltreleasefilenameinformation)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. For me, the problem was that the mini-filter template was not showing in the templates listing for new projects and so I had to create it from scratch and I inevitably missed something.  After cross-checking the linker options against the minifilter projects provided by Microsoft as reference ([check here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/filesys/miniFilter)) I realized that `fltMgr.lib` has to be specifically provided to the linker. In order to do that right-click on the project in the "Solution Explorer" left pane. Then go to `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`. Add `$(DDK_LIB_PATH)\fltMgr.lib` to the list of additional dependencies and rebuild your project!
I hope this does it for you, but like the Microsoft documentation points out `LNK2019` can be caused by lots of other problems with your configuration.